# ATMega32u4 power consumption with CLKDIV8

Tags: low-power, power-consumption, atmega32u4

I have a little board with an ATMega32u4, that's run straight off USB voltage. There are no peripherals on board that should draw power (no LDOs or anything, LED is off).

It has a 16MHz crystal.

The power consumption (measured using a multimeter) is at 40mA. If I set CLKDIV8, the consumption drops to 14.5mA. When I am using CLKPR to slow the clock, the power consumption changes by less than 1mA.

According to the data sheet, the active supply current at 16MHz/5V should be around 13mA and at 2Mhz/5V it should be <3mA.

Where does the power consumption difference come from?

I couldn't find anything regarding if USB increases the power consumption that much. The only thing I could find was that the USB voltage regulator requires a few microampere. That should not make the difference.

What am I missing?

The board I am using is the ATMega32u4-based Beetle:

[image: Beetle]

It's almost as bare as can be. There are no components on the backside.

Comment: A schematic would be better. Are you sure about the accuracy of your multimeter?

Comment: Without 50mV current sensing resistors on board, it's hard to guess.  Compare with RESET current specs. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngs3T.png  Is this board your design with details or do you have a link?

Comment: These types of tests are hard to diagnose without special tools such as measuring port capacitance of high speed clocks with a Huntron tracker looking for wounded ports from ESD.

Comment: For comparison: I have a Teensy2.0 board (ATMega32u4 + some caps and crystal). With activated USB feature but unconnected interface it consumes 25 mA running at 16 MHz without any power reduction options. Reset current is 10.5 mA. You might have a shorted or ESD damaged output pin.

Comment: Have you initialized the unused IO pins in any way or not? What if you set all IO pins as inputs with pull-up enabled, or outputs?